# Java upload file with multipart / form-data and authentication

Tags: java, multipartform-data, talend

With Talend Open Studio I have to upload a file to a WebService with multipart / form-data. There is no standard object in talend to do this POST call, so I'm trying to do it via Java (tJavaRow), but can't find a solution. The WS has basic authentication. Can someone help me?

Thanks,
Diego

Answer (score -2):

Would you mind going through the below URL's for tRest and tRestclient components in Talend, you could implement all methods in web services.

[https://help.talend.com/reader/rQsosxHOgaPa8zBCi83PLA/T~lWgeKbmUvwzc6QDx301w](https://help.talend.com/reader/rQsosxHOgaPa8zBCi83PLA/T%7ElWgeKbmUvwzc6QDx301w)
https://help.talend.com/reader/7NvFnkWpbH8Gy3Rm6mUXnw/ECeCwoP1aVopmhqJe_dENA

Comment: thank you, i have already read this doc, but without a solution